# Set numpy array values to zero where x,y,z are not all multiples of n

Tags: python, numpy

Here is a naive implementation of a function which sets every value of a numpy array with index x,y,z to zero if any of x,y, or z is not a multiple of one_per_n:

```
import numpy as np

X = np.random.rand(10,10,10)

one_per_n = 4

for x in range(X.shape[0]):
    for y in range(X.shape[1]):
        for z in range(X.shape[2]):
            if x % one_per_n != 0 or y % one_per_n != 0 or z % one_per_n != 0:
                X[x,y,z] = 0
```

I am looking for a more efficient method.

Comment: You could vectorize it partially with three consecutive loops: `for x in range(X.shape[0]): if x % one_per_n != 0: X[x,:,:] = 0` and ditto for y and z.

Comment: Better yet, if there's a way to create a slices with gaps in it, `X[x_slice,:,:] = 0` would be even faster, but I don't know how to express such a slice.

Comment: The x_slice in your 2nd comment can be [i for i in range(X.shape[0]) if i%one_per_n]

Comment: Indeed @Michael Szczesny, copying X values for x,y,z multiples of n is simpler to code. You might want to formulate an answer based on that comment (for posterity and other users to find :) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In each dimension, the elements that retain their values are the ones where the modulo is zero. They are spaced `one_per_n` apart, so utilizing a slice with `one_per_n` as step size is useful.

You can construct a mask of elements to set to 0 for each dimension, and then zero out X at all these positions.

The inverse of

```
# elements to set to zero
(x % one_per_n != 0) or (y % one_per_n != 0) or (z % one_per_n != 0)
```

is

```
# elements to keep
(x % one_per_n == 0) and (y % one_per_n == 0) and (z % one_per_n == 0)
```

As the inverse selection masks are connected by logical ands, they can be sliced at the same time:

```
# init with zeroing out everything
zero_out_mask = np.ones_like(X, dtype=bool)

# except for the modulo == 0 elements
zero_out_mask[::one_per_n, ::one_per_n, ::one_per_n] = False

X[zero_out_mask] = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

A quite literal numpy vectorization of the code would be:

```
x, y, z = np.indices(X.shape, sparse=True)
X[(x % one_per_n != 0) | (y % one_per_n != 0) | (z % one_per_n != 0)] = 0
```

This is still fairly efficient because modulus is only computed for 1D arrays thanks to `sparse=True`.

Comment: Uhh nice idea! Even though x, y, z are sparse, I believe by stringing the dimensions together with `|`, it will broadcast into a full non-sparse mask again, same as `zero_out_mask`. On my machine for shape (100, 100, 100) it's a little bit (like 10%) slower than constructing the mask outright.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to solve this without creating the full non-sparse mask. And even inverting the problem by copying only the non-zero elements to a new array (`Y = np.zeros_like(X); Y[::one_per_n, ::one_per_n, ::one_per_n] = X[::one_per_n, ::one_per_n, ::one_per_n]`) is a little bit slower on my machine.

Comment: @w-m Indeed the mask becomes full size with the last `|`. But taking the modulus for a full size array would be really slow, having `sparse=False` runs 10x slower for me, also tested on a (100, 100, 100)  array.